# Prevent going back and changing the text written in the text area

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that the person typing cannot press the left arrow key or using the mouse to click on a point in the text that is to the left.

Comment: give us some code to see and work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to prevent certain actions. For example, if you have a `<textarea>` element:

```js
$("#my-textarea").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 37) { // if the key pressed is the left arrow key...
    e.preventDefault(); // ... stop the left arrow key default action
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="my-textarea">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed consectetur justo. Nam ut metus nec sapien volutpat suscipit. Ut ex nunc, tincidunt in commodo non, tempor nec mi. Vivamus sit amet leo vulputate tortor posuere gravida faucibus in est. Maecenas finibus, nulla sed feugiat faucibus, turpis nulla dignissim neque, id aliquam felis ligula quis velit.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').on('keypress', function(evt) {
if ((evt.keyCode === 37) || (evt.keyCode ==
evt.preventDefault();
}
});
$('textarea').onclick(function(){
event.preventDefault();
return false;
});
});
```

This will prevent back arrow and delete and on click over the textarea.